# What am I doing wrong, when I'm trying to update my products?

Tags: javascript

This is my JS, and it looks like it doesn't want to send me back to the addProduct.html page with the updated products.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

  const idLoaded = urlParams.get("id");

  const productLoaded = urlParams.get("product");
  document.getElementById("product").value = productLoaded;

  const priceLoaded = urlParams.get("price");
  document.getElementById("price").value = priceLoaded;

  const categoryLoaded = urlParams.get("category");
  document.getElementById("category").value = categoryLoaded;

  document.getElementById("update").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();


    const product = document.getElementById("product").value;
    const price = document.getElementById("price").value;
    const category = document.getElementById("category").value;
    // slet nedenstående
    const params = new URL(location.href).searchParams;


    const urlId = params.get("id");
    const urlProduct = params.get("product");
    const urlPrice = params.get("price");
    // slet nedenstående 
    id.value = urlId
    product.value = urlProduct
    price.value = urlPrice


    document.getElementById("update-products").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      //slet nedenstående
      // const currentProduct = product.value
      // const currentPrice = price.value

      const payload = {
        id: idLoaded,
        product: product,
        price: price,
        category: category

      };


      /*
             const payload = {
                 "id": urlId,
                 "product": currentProduct,
                 "price": currentPrice
             }
             */

      fetch("http://localhost:5005/products/update", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(payload),
        })
        //.then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
          if (response) {
            window.alert("Congrats!")
            location.href = "/addProduct.html";
          }
        })
        .catch(() => {
          window.alert("Error.")
        });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Opdater varer detaljer</title>
  <script src="updateProduct.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- ændr til update-->
  <form id="update-products">
    Product: <input type="text" name="product" id="product" value=""><br> Price: <input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my product html, which shows added products as well as the updated products, which dosen't work:

I have a json file that is connected to all the products.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="addProduct.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <title> addProduct</title>
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Opret en vare</h1>
    <p class="addProduct">Tilføj en vare ved at udfylde felterne</p>
    <form id="products">
      <input class="product" placeholder="Vare" id="product">
      <input class="price" placeholder="Pris" id="price">
      <select name="category" id="category">
        <option value="Borde">Borde</option>
        <option value="Stole">Stole</option>
        <option value="Kopper">Kopper</option>
        <option value="Kander">Kander</option>
      </select>
      <input class="picture" id="picture" type="file" accept="image/*">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Tilføj">
    </form>
    <p>Vil du fjerne din vare?</p>
    <form id="delete">
      <input value="Slet vare" type="submit">
    </form>
    <br>
    <table id="varer">
      <tr>
        <th>Produkt</th>
        <th>Pris</th>
        <th>Kategori</th>
        <th>Billede</th>
        <th>Handlinger</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <a href="index.html"> Hjem</a>

    <form id="delete">
      <input value="Delete" type="submit" />
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239732/discussion-on-question-by-claudio-truong-what-am-i-doing-wrong-when-im-trying).

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
   document.getElementById("update-products").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
```

and change

```
   document.getElementById("update").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
```

to

```
   document.getElementById("update-products").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
```

and add a category or remove the code that sets it

Remove

```
// slet nedenstående 
id.value = urlId
product.value = urlProduct
price.value = urlPrice
```

and change to

```
const payload = {
  id: idLoaded,
  product: product,
  price: price,
  category: category
};
```

lastly you need to change the URL handling - see the code I added

Also I prefer

`window.addEventListener("load", () => {`
to DOMContentLoaded

Like this

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  // remove the line under
  const url = new URL("https://minside.dk/search?id=999&product=krus&category=kopper&price=25.99") // new URL(window.location.href);
  // remove comments
  // const url = new URL(window.location.href);
  const urlParams = url.searchParams;

  const idLoaded = urlParams.get("id");
  const productLoaded = urlParams.get("product");
  const priceLoaded = urlParams.get("price");
  const categoryLoaded = urlParams.get("category");

  document.getElementById("category").value = categoryLoaded;
  document.getElementById("price").value = priceLoaded;
  document.getElementById("product").value = productLoaded;

  document.getElementById("update-products").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const product = document.getElementById("product").value;
    const price = document.getElementById("price").value; // should not actually be allowed to be changed?
    const category = document.getElementById("category").value;
    urlParams.set("product", product);
    urlParams.set("price", price);
    urlParams.set("category", category); // should not really change, should it?

    const payload = {
      id: idLoaded,
      product: product,
      price: price,
      category: category
    };

    fetch("http://localhost:5005/products/update", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      })
      //.then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        if (response) {
          window.alert("Congrats!")
          location.href = url.toString();
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        window.alert("Error.")
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Opdater varer detaljer</title>
  <script src="updateProduct.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- ændr til update-->
  <form id="update-products">
    Product: <input type="text" name="product" id="product" value="" /><br/> Price: <input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="" /> Category: <input type="text" name="category" id="category" value="" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```